# Pass data between ViewControllers in a non-based storyboard app

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I am creating an iOS app without Storyboard, setting the window's frame in the AppDelegate.

Now, I have 2 view controllers the ViewController and the SettingsController. In the settings controller I have created a text field(myTextField) I want to store the myTextField.text in a variable.
How can I do?

Comment: First search on google and learn basic concepts.

Comment: I know how to do this with storyboard, but how without I can't find nothing on internet, so if you know how to I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Check my answer.

Comment: use prepareForSegue to pass data between viewControllers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create one public property inside AppDelegate file,

```
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSString *passingText;
```

1. ViewController 2 import Appdelegate:

```
    @interface viewcontroller2()
    {
     AppDelegate *appdelegate;
    }
    @end

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
     appdelegate = (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication SharedApplication].delegate;
    }
    Once user entered text in myTextField, using delegate:

    - (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextfield *)textField
    {
     appdelegate.passingText = textField.text;

    }
```

On second controller you can read the value of appdelegate.

This will help to solve your requirement.

Comment: in here question is based on custom protocols, passing data between VC2 to VC1

Answer (score -2):

SecondViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol SecondViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

@optional
- (void)secondViewDidEndEditingText:(UITextField *)textField;

@end

@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, weak) id<SecondViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

SecondViewController.m

```
#import "SecondViewController.h"

@interface SecondViewController ()<UITextFieldDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, strong) UITextField *textField;
@end

@implementation SecondViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self textField];
}

- (UITextField *)textField
{
    if (!_textField) {
        _textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 50, 80, 40)];
        _textField.delegate = self;
        [self.view addSubview:_textField];
    }
    return _textField;
}

- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(secondViewDidEndEditingText:)]) {
        [self.delegate secondViewDidEndEditingText:textField];
    }
}

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "SecondViewController.h"
@interface ViewController ()<SecondViewControllerDelegate>

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    SecondViewController *secondVC = [SecondViewController new];
    secondVC.delegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:secondVC animated:YES completion:NULL];
}

- (void)secondViewDidEndEditingText:(UITextField *)textField
{
    NSLog(@"SecondViewControllerText:%@", textField.text);
}


@end
```

Comment: in here question is based on custom protocols, passing data between VC2 to VC1

Comment: This first code snippet is wrong. Also, using UserDefaults for the purpose of passing data between view controllers is *not* a good idea at all.

Comment: Because my English is not good, I did not understand his question, now understand. I re-edited my answer.